# Ограничение ввода в QLineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qlineedit

Как сделать так, чтобы в `QLineEdit` можно было ввести не больше 20 символов, ЛЮБЫХ и цифр, и букв?

Знаю только, как ограничить для цифр, а как и для букв и цифр одновременно сложновато.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у класса `QLineEdit` есть есть метод `setMaxLength(<длина>)` вы можете просто вызвать его прямо при создании виджета:

```
edit1 = QLineEdit(<родитель>) 
edit1.setMaxLength(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно настроить [маску ввода](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

app = Qt.QApplication([])

line_edit = Qt.QLineEdit()
line_edit.setInputMask('x' * 20)
line_edit.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: вариант несколько костыльный, да рабочий, но зачем использовать маску? что если нужно поле без маски? или маска нужна меньше чем максимальная длина? к слову для всех участников вопроса и для его автора советую посмотреть книгу "python и PyQt5 разработка приложений" в части про PyQt подробно рассказано о многих виджетах, и для всех из рассмотренных подробно рассказано о ВСЕХ их методах и полях

Comment: @NEStenerusnester потому что ваш вариант не единственный на свете рабочий. Тогда не использовать маску, если она не нужна. Маска с `x` как раз такая -- вам не потребуется вводить все 20 символов. Можно и без книги -- документация по Qt очень хорошая я с ней еще с c++/Qt знаком и при вопросах по pyqt к ней обращаюсь, например как для этого ответа: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,  QLineEdit , QWidget ,  QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator, QRegExpValidator 
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QRegExp 

class LineEditDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineEditDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример проверки QLineEdit в PyQt5")

        flo = QFormLayout()
        pIntLineEdit        = QLineEdit()
        pDoubleLineEdit     = QLineEdit()
        pValidatorLineEdit  = QLineEdit()

        flo.addRow("Цылые числа",         pIntLineEdit)
        flo.addRow("Тип плавающей точки", pDoubleLineEdit)
        flo.addRow("Буквы и цыфры",       pValidatorLineEdit)

        pIntLineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Цылые числа: `[1, 99]`");
        pDoubleLineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Тип плавающей точки: `123,12`");
        pValidatorLineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Буквы и цыфры: `[а-яА-Я0-9]{20}`");

        # QIntValidator предоставляет валидатор, который гарантирует, что строка содержит 
        # допустимое целое число в указанном диапазоне [1, 99].
        pIntValidator = QIntValidator(self)
        pIntValidator.setRange(1, 99)

        # QDoubleValidator обеспечивает проверку диапазона чисел с плавающей запятой.
        pDoubleValidator = QDoubleValidator(self)
        pDoubleValidator.setRange(-360, 360)
        pDoubleValidator.setNotation(QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation)
        pDoubleValidator.setDecimals(2)

        # символы и цифры
        reg = QRegExp("[а-яА-Я0-9]{20}")
        pValidator = QRegExpValidator(self)
        pValidator.setRegExp(reg)   

        # Установить валидатор
        pIntLineEdit.setValidator(pIntValidator)
        pDoubleLineEdit.setValidator(pDoubleValidator)
        pValidatorLineEdit.setValidator(pValidator)

        self.setLayout(flo)                        

if __name__ == "__main__":       
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = LineEditDemo()    
    win.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]